# Number of Iterations Exceeded - Salesforce Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am dealing with two objects: Accounts and Donor Programs.

Accts and DPs have a lookup relationship via the Accts.[Donor Program] field. Accts.[Donor Program] field populates with 'Partner' if a donor donates a certain amount.

I have a scheduled triggered flow that loops through all 'partner' accounts (low-level donors).  Then, it updates the "roll-up summaries" to the *Partners Donors Programs* record on the DP object.

Because the flow is looping through a big set of data, it has exceeded the number of iterations.

[image]
[image]
[image]

In attempts to resolve this, I have tried the using event platform suggested in [this post](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/bypassing-the-number-of-iterations-exceeded-error-in-salesforce-flows-with-platform-events/). and also the [DSLR](https://www.salesforceben.com/guide-to-salesforce-dlrs-declarative-lookup-roll-up-summaries/) -- but so far no luck.

How to bypass the [number of iterations exceeded error](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382258&language=en_US&type=1#:%7E:text=If%20your%20flow%20hit%20the,executed%20elements%20at%20run%20time.) as mentioned in the knowledge article:

- Reduce the total number of records being processed. Process the records in multiple batches.
- Keep your own counter using a number variable and increment it every loop, exiting the loop when you're about to hit a limit.
- Consider adding a screen or wait element before looping through next batch of records.
- Check for alternatives using Apex code.

See my previous post for additional info: [Trigger to Count Number of Accounts to Custom Object Field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/403484/trigger-to-count-number-of-accounts-to-custom-object-field)

Comment: Hi, @DragonBallz, since the quantity of records is large, I would recommend you use an imperative approach with Apex. If you have more than 2.000 records to loop through, a flow may not be the best option.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding - Would you have any sample codes? I tried on a different post - 

trigger AcctUpdateDonorProgram on Account (after update){

    List<Donor_Programs__c> partnersDonorProgramUpdate = new List<Donor_Programs__c>();

    for(Account newAccts : Trigger.new){ 
            if (newAccts.Donor_Program__c == 'Partners'){
                Donor_Programs__c dp = new Donor_Programs__c();
                dp.Total_Members__c += 1;
                partnersDonorProgramUpdate.add(dp);
            }
        }
        update partnersDonorProgramUpdate;
}

Comment: And I am getting this error: "Invalid loop variable type expected Donor_Programs__c was Account"  I am not understanding exactly how object-oriented language work (still learning - any guidance on this would be super helpful). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @DragonBallz. You cannot use update in that context, because you are instantiating a new Donor_Programs__c, adding it to the partnersDonorProgramUpdate, but those new Donor_Programs__c do not exist in the database. Also "dp.Total_Members__c += 1" is not correct: On every iteration you create a new instance of Donor_Programs__c, each instance is going to be a record in the system, with Total_Members__c  = 1.